# Access object's properties in object definition

Tags: javascript, json

so I have an object definition that looks like this:

```
var Foo = window.Foo = {
  MIN_ROWS : 10,
  MIN_COLS : 10,

  NUM_ROWS : (function(){ return Math.max( parseInt(this.params.rows) || 0, this.MIN_ROWS); })(),

  // etc...

  params: (function(){ /* ... */ })() // parses the GET querystring parameters from the URL and returns as a JSON object

}
```

For the `NUM_ROWS` property, I want to set it to be `Foo.params.rows` if it exists and it's greater than `MIN_ROWS`, otherwise set it to `MIN_ROWS`.

I've already figured out the logic for this, the only thing that's giving me trouble is **when I self-invoke the function as above, the `this` variable refers to `window` and not to `Foo` as I would expect it to**. (This is the error message I get in the console: `"TypeError: Result of expression 'this.params' [undefined] is not an object."` )

If I don't self-invoke the function, it works perfectly. However, I'd like to have `NUM_ROWS` be an integer, not a function, so that I can access it as `Foo.NUM_ROWS` and not `Foo.NUM_ROWS()` in the other parts of my code.

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: To those who advise defining `params` before `NUM_ROWS`: I don't think it matters.

I've tried moving `params` above `NUM_ROWS` and I still get the same error message.

This error is saying that `'this.params' [undefined] is not an object`, but in this context, the `'this'` is referring to the global `window` object, not the `Foo` object, as discovered by inserting `console.log(this)` at the start of my `NUM_ROWS` function.

Comment: answer updated ... actually, it is quite logical for this to be window, because it always is in functions called as functions, instead of being called as methods ...

Comment: @gabriel, I had a quick look at this, and changed my post, you probably got this sorted. It's been a while since I looked at js without using a framework, so you can probably get it better than my example but I hope it solves the problems you were having with the this keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed it, I simplified the code a bit, but you should get the idea, if you haven't already, hope it helps. The link below is definately worth following if you're into getting your javascript nailed.

```
var FooFactory = function(){
  this.MIN_ROWS = 10;
  this.MIN_COLS = 10;
  this.params = { rows : 12};

  this.NUM_ROWS = Math.max( parseInt(this.params.rows) || 0, this.MIN_ROWS);
  // etc...
};
var Foo = window.Foo = new FooFactory();

document.write(Foo.NUM_ROWS);
```

this in JavaScript is the object that is calling, not the the object being called, you need to look at Doug Crockford's site to get some good articles on what this means, and how it affects your usage in this case.

[This article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) in particular shows you what this is all about

Answer (score 0):

why don't you initialize `params` before `NUM_ROWS`?  `params` is not available yet at the time ...

other than that, you might wanna declare a getter ...

---

**edit:** well, in that case, a getter is really a good option ... won't work to well in IE though ...
apart from that, you can always build the object step by step ...

```
var Foo = window.Foo = {
  MIN_ROWS : 10,
  MIN_COLS : 10
}
Foo.params = //parse input
Foo.NUM_ROWS = Math.max( parseInt(Foo.params.rows) || 0, Foo.MIN_ROWS));
```

or maybe this way:

```
var params = //parse input
var NUM_ROWS = Math.max( parseInt(params.rows) || 0, this.MIN_ROWS));
var Foo = window.Foo = {
  MIN_ROWS : 10,
  MIN_COLS : 10
  params: params,
  NUM_ROWS: NUM_ROWS
}
```

yes, it's not so funky as what you tried to use, but it simply works ... plus it saves you at least one call ...

---

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve anything. Please see my comment above.